# How to display an array in JSX from a function in React?

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I implemented a function where I fetch all Docs from a Firebase collection on a click.

Now I want to display each doc I fetched in a `<div>` container in JSX. When I try to take the array and display it, I´m getting the error that the array is not found.

This is my code:

```
async function getAllDivs(){
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Div"))
  const allDivs = [];
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    allDivs.push(doc.data().DivContent);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the part where you attempt to display it?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything. Also, note that `const allDivs` is `querySnapshop.map(doc => doc.data().DivContent)`. No need to create an empty array and then push elements one by one.

Comment: Yes first I just tried to display anything like this <div>{allDivs}</div> but then I realised that allDivs are only defined within a function.

Comment: Where does `getDocs` come from?

Comment: @StevanKostic That still won't work as you have it. Please refer to my answer, where I'm rendering the elements in the return block.

Comment: I think you might need to make your request from a `useEffect` and store the results in some sort of state.

Comment: @Camilo I think they're just starting out, so let's just answer their question so as not to overwhelm them yet.

Comment: @StevanKostic remember to accept an answer if it is the correct one!

Answer (score 0):

You would have to return the array from the function, because of the "[scope](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp)".

Example:

```js
//your current function
async function getAllDivs(){
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(collection(db, "Div"));
  return querySnapshot.map((doc) => doc.data().DivContent);
}

//your component
let divs = getAllDivs(); //you can now use "divs" in this scope

return (
    <>
        divs.map((current_div) => { <div>{current_div}</div> })
    </>
)
```

Also, I suggest against pushing data to an array labeled as `const`, as it could be confusing for someone else reading your code.

Comment: `getAllDivs` is not returning anything, `divs` will always be `undefined`.

Comment: @Camilo Sorry about that, I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use something like this:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [docs, setDocs] = useState();

  const onClickHandler = async () => {
    const docs = await getDocs(collection(db, "Div"));

    setDocs(docs);
  }
    
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={onClickHandler}>Get docs</button>
      {docs && docs.map(doc => (
        <div>{doc.data().DivContent}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}
```

If `DivContent` contains HTML you can use [`dangerouslySetInnerHTML`](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml).